Why does this regex with a lazy quantifier match exactly 2 digits?
The regex is: ([0-9]+?)*.
The command line is: echo 12345678 | grep -E -o '([0-9]+?)*', and the output is:
12
34
56
78

where as I expect a single line: 12345678, since the outter-most quantifier is a greedy one.
The grep in question conforms to 2024 edition of the POSIX standard, the one I use is shipped with macOS 15. Austin Group as a tracked bug that discuss various aspects of existing ambiguities and mis-wordings, but so far we all agree the regex used by standard interfaces should use the shortest match rather than least repetition.
Which begs the question - in what way does the above output conform to the description of the standard or the newly proposed wording?
Update
I'd like to protest the duplicate closure reason. This question asks about the semantic of new POSIX-2024 ERE regex semantic, whereas the referred question ask how to achieve a non-greedy/lazy match. The former is more of a standard-lawyer type question, whereas the latter is more of a practical one.

Interesting question - perhaps it would be even clearer if you stated what output you actually expect? I presume this is more like single-character matches, "1", "2", "3", etc.?

That version of BSD grep is buggy on this. gnu grep will behave differently and output only 12345678

@rwp You're right, the overall expression should be 8 chars, each correspond to an instance of parenthesesed subexpression

@anubhava GNU Grep doesn't support lazy/non-greedy quantifiers as of 2024-12-01. I checked their docs.

Regex101 agrees with your expectation. So this is just a bug in the MacOS version of grep.

@DannyNiu: I have installed GNU grep 3.11 on my Mac and it does support lazy/non-greedy quantifiers using -P (perl) mode.

@anubhava The Perl/Python/PHP sementic of lazy quantifier is different from that of POSIX-2024. PCRE regices use least repetition, where as POSIX specifies shortest character (not byte!) string length.
